# What is the difference between "have an issue" ,"facing an issue", "have got an issue"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage

If I'm contacting customer support of a software company to report an issue with the software prodct that I purchased from them what is the correct usage?

1. I have an issue
2. I'm facing an issue
3. I've got an issue

Comment: They're all fine, and they all mean the same. Use whichever you like best.

Answer (score 2):

They mean the same, and they are equally good.

"I've got an issue" is a bit more informal and you find "I've got" more frequently in BrE.

*Problem* is also a suitable word here. You can face/run into/encounter a problem.

You might say it in a past tense as well.

> I've run into a problem.

> I encountered a problem.